# How can I secure the connection the server and connected devices when using IBM's "Internet of Things Foundation"?

Tags: mqtt, ibm-cloud, iot

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/) for IBM's ["Internet of Things" managed host platform](https://developer.ibm.com/iotfoundation/), I'm supposed to use [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) as the protocol when connecting my devices to the cloud service.

How can I configure the service to ensure the data between my devices and the cloud is encrypted?

Do I need to configure security at the messaging or transport layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM IoTF service will accept an [encrypted client connection](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/messaging/mqtt.html#/) using TLS to secure the link. Connect to the service using port 8883 (or 443 for websockets) for a TLS-secured connection with a compatible client library.

Certificate file (messaging.pem) for the *.messaging.internetofthingscloud.ibmcloud.com chain is available [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-python/blob/master/src/ibmiotf/messaging.pem).

The IoT Foundation requires TLS v1.2.